# Async POST request using Jetty 9 HttpClient

Tags: java

I am trying to develop a high load generating async HttpClient using Jetty 9 HttpClient API. I  have written the basic code for doing POST requests

```
public void connectHttp() throws Exception {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();       
    // Configure HttpClient here
    client.setMaxConnectionsPerDestination(1000);       

    try {
        client.start();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Caught Exception in Client Start : ");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    try {
        for(int i = 0 ; i<1000;i++) {
            client.POST("http://localhost:8080/privaterestservice/jersey/privatedata/writedata")
            .timeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .file(Paths.get("stats_kestrel.txt"),"text/plain").send(new BufferingResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Result res) {
                    System.out.println("Got Response : "+res.isSucceeded());
                                        }
            });         
        }

    }
    finally {
        //client.stop();
    }
    System.out.println("I am Done!!");
    System.out.println(client.getState());
}
```

I need to bombard the server with lot of requests. But when i run this code, it fails for the last few requests. I checked using Jmeter and there is no problem with the server. Also the code does not stop even after all the requests are completed.

How to make the code quit after all the responses are received instead of the threads going to sleep state?

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Could you, please share the error which you have with last few requests? You can handle this error and log.

Comment: @AlexanderBezrodniy The last few requests fail due to time out. Just found that out and if i remove the timeout specified in the request, the errors disappear. The problem now is to make sure the threads die after the last response is received.

Answer (score 5):

You should use CountDownLatch, something like:

```
public void connectHttp() throws Exception {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();       
    // Configure HttpClient here
    client.setMaxConnectionsPerDestination(1000);       
    CountDownLatch countDown = new CountDownLatch(1000);
    try {
        client.start();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Caught Exception in Client Start : ");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    try {
        for(int i = 0 ; i<1000;i++) {
            client.POST("http://localhost:8080/privaterestservice/jersey/privatedata/writedata")
            .timeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .file(Paths.get("stats_kestrel.txt"),"text/plain").send(new BufferingResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Result res) {
                    System.out.println("Got Response : "+res.isSucceeded());
                    countDown.countDown();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Response response, Throwable failure) {
                    countDown.countDown();
                }
            });         
        }

    }
    finally {
        //client.stop();
    }
    countDown.await();
    System.out.println("I am Done!!");
    System.out.println(client.getState());
}
```

It will wait until all responses will complete.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderBezrodniy. I wrote the BufferingResponseListener as a separate derived class and used static variables to count the response.